# Chrome displays question marks instead of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-el-capitan

I'm having an issue with Chrome Mac OSX, across multiple sites, where kbd elements are not rendered correctly.

[Chrome Displaying Question Marks Instead of Keyboard Shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDOGr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an encoding issue: I had the "wrong" character coding. Click the wrench icon in the toolbar, then Tools, and  Encoding. Changing to Unicode (UTF-8) should do the trick.

I don't know what encoding you are currently using, but UTF-8 should work for english.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Unfortunately, the setting was already set to UTF-8